# Can't deploy flow to HA cluster of Apache Flink using Flink CLI

Tags: apache-flink

I can deploy flow to standalone installation of Apache Flink (with one JobManager and several TaskManagers) without problem:

```
bin/flink run -m example-app-1.stag.local:6123 -d -p 4 my-flow-fat-jar.jar <flow parameters>
```

but when I run the same command and deploy to Standalone HA cluster this command raise error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: JobManager did not respond within 60000 milliseconds
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.runDetached(Client.java:406)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.runDetached(Client.java:366)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.DetachedEnvironment.finalizeExecute(DetachedEnvironment.java:75)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.runDetached(Client.java:278)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgramDetached(CliFrontend.java:844)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1189)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1239)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobTimeoutException: JobManager did not respond within 60000 milliseconds
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.submitJobDetached(JobClient.java:221)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.runDetached(Client.java:403)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [60000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.Await.result(package.scala)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.submitJobDetached(JobClient.java:218)
    ... 8 more
```

Active Job Manager write the following errors to log:

```
2016-04-14 13:54:44,160 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:62784] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
2016-04-14 13:54:46,299 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Discard message LeaderSessionMessage(null,TriggerSavepoint(5de582462f334caee4733c60c6d69fd7)) because the expected leader session ID Some(72630119-fd0a-40e7-8372-45c93781e99f) did not equal the received leader session ID None.
```

So, I don't understand what can cause such error?

Let me known if required additional information.

P.S.

Deploy from Flink Dashboard works fine for Standalone HA cluster. Such problem appear when I deploy through Flink CLI only.

**Update**

I clear Zookeeper, clear directories used by Flink on disk and re-deploy Flink Standalone HA cluster. Then I try to run flow use `bin/flink run` command. As you can see JobManager write only one line about problem (see flink--jobmanager-0-example-app-1.stag.local.log).

- [flink--jobmanager-0-example-app-1.stag.local.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxd/790937d5b43d79898913fc71a3b3b02e/raw/8bfc1bf3e9aea7782948fc66437816fcb36650e2/flink--jobmanager-0-example-app-1.stag.local.log)
- [flink--jobmanager-0-example-app-2.stag.local.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxd/beafd603996bbee2799fa741d2767504/raw/88cfef76ef21c1e944008a3a7bea142826936b05/flink--jobmanager-0-example-app-2.stag.local.log)
- [flink--taskmanager-0-example-app-1.stag.local.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxd/7d4b8c8da35d56a9f1e539eb3ba5e13e/raw/f76160b207ce5cdc4493fe80d4b1043313f86117/flink--taskmanager-0-example-app-1.stag.local.log)
- [flink--taskmanager-0-example-app-2.stag.local.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxd/7aae159058a0f6aca27966332e61217f/raw/0dfd36cbd62124bdb88d39f03f3dd47cad4b0bd1/flink--taskmanager-0-example-app-2.stag.local.log)

All JobManagers and TaskManagers use the same `flink-conf.yaml`:

```
jobmanager.heap.mb: 1024
jobmanager.web.port: 8081

taskmanager.data.port: 6121
taskmanager.heap.mb: 2048
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 4
taskmanager.memory.preallocate: false
taskmanager.tmp.dirs: /flink/data/task_manager

blob.server.port: 6130
blob.storage.directory: /flink/data/blob_storage

parallelism.default: 4

state.backend: filesystem
state.backend.fs.checkpointdir: s3a://example-flink/checkpoints

restart-strategy: none
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts: 2
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.delay: 60s

recovery.mode: zookeeper
recovery.zookeeper.quorum: zookeeper-1.stag.local:2181,zookeeper-2.stag.local:2181,zookeeper-3.stag.local:2181
recovery.zookeeper.path.root: /example/flink
recovery.zookeeper.storageDir: s3a://example-flink/recovery
recovery.jobmanager.port: 6123

fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: /flink/conf
```

So, seems like Standalone HA cluster configured correctly.

**Update 2**

FYI: I want to install Standalone HA cluster as described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/setup/jobmanager_high_availability.html#standalone-cluster-high-availability). Not YARN HA cluster.

**Update 3**

Here is log created by `bin/flink` CLI: [flink-username-client-hostname.local.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxd/2c1184a3d21fa2c725c438ea31eb9d8f/raw/e5b76006f974ad21fa1d60a8ca48ddc90640593b/flink-username-client-hostname.local.log).

Comment: Could you paste the complete jobmanager log?

Comment: Have you set the proper HA settings in the `flink-conf.yaml` which is used by the cli (thus the one in `FLINK_HOME/conf/flink-conf.yaml`)?

Comment: @TillRohrmann I have added logs and `flink-conf.yaml`. Do you see any problems?

Comment: You're right, this not only applies to the yarn cluster but also to the standalone cluster. So whenever you use HA you have to set these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting a Flink cluster in HA mode, the `JobManager` address and its leader id are written to the specified ZooKeeper cluster. In order to communicate with the `JobManager` you have not only to know the address but also its leader address. Therefore, you have to specify the following parameters in your 'flink-conf.yaml` which is read by the CLI.

```
recovery.mode: zookeeper
recovery.zookeeper.quorum: address of your cluster
recovery.zookeeper.path.root: ZK path you've started your cluster with
```

With this information the client knows where it can find the ZooKeeper cluster and where to find the `JobManager` address and its leader id.

Comment: You want to say that `bin/flink` CLI are using settings from `flink-conf.yaml`. Right?

Comment: I have copied `flink-conf.yaml` from my Standalone HA cluster into my dev environment and run `bin/flink run`. After that my flow started in HA cluster. I think this is bad idea to read part of settings from `flink-conf.yaml` because this is absolutely not a clear for understanding and `bin/flink` should have arguments required to connect to Standalone HA cluster.